# Partner Community User to see Notes RL

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-experience, notes

I am trying to show the Notes Related List on community page for a user having Partner Community user license, but its not coming up. Also, I want to add notes from community which I want to share with other users. Any direction which i can explore.

Comment: which community page are you using? what community template?

Comment: @ItaiShmida Customer Community and Partner Community with Customer Service (Napili) template.